# npm run build not creating build folder for production server

Tags: reactjs

I am running command npm run build for making build for the production server. But it is not creating build folder.

$ npm run build

[I am attaching image of result after run npm run build command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6sAI.png)

Comment: You should add more information, did you use `create-react-app` or others ?

Comment: I add a screenshot it is more clear for you. No I did not use create-react-app @thelonglqd